# Java Mail API - Can't set port correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getDefaultInstance%28java.util.Properties%29) [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#getdefaultinstance), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771167/how-to-change-javamail-port), you should use more ore less always use the getInstance() method of the Java Mail API to set the properties correctly.

So let's check my code:

```
[...]
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
properties.put("mail.imap.port", "143");
properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");  
properties.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
properties.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
session.setDebug(true);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(host, userName, password);

Folder imapFolder = store.getFolder(folderName);
imapFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);


Message[] messages = imapFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new 
lags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

[...]
```

See my port property set to "143"? Let's jump to the mail api debug console output:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 213.189.150.34 r25-v6mb373781038edd
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! r25-v6mb373781038edd
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user="myuser", password="mypassword"
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK "myuser" authenticated (Success)
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
A2 OK Success
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT WhiteListedMembers
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 12] UIDs valid.
* 379 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 386] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 65275]
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] WhiteListedMembers selected. (Success)
A4 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH
A4 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
Unreaded messages in inbox: 0
A5 UNSELECT
A5 OK Returned to authenticated state. (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
A6 LOGOUT
```

My questions is: Why does java mail api still use the port 993? Is there a automatic port mapping in place?
I just can't understand this.

Can someone bring light into this?

Many thanks for your answers and your sponsored time.

Best regards
Matt

OS: Windows 10, Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0, Java Oracle JRE 1.8.0 131, Java Mail API 1.5.6

Comment: Tried `mail.imaps.port=143`?

Comment: Dear Usagi, correct. Works now as expected. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you really running IMAP-with-SSL on port 143?  That would be "unusual" at best.

If you're using the default ports, you don't need to set the port properties.  Just use the "imap" protocol and set the "mail.imap.ssl.enable" property and JavaMail will choose the correct default port.

Comment: Bill, thanks for your comment. The 143 was just a test port that for sure fails. Iirc google mail uses the standard imap-with-ssl port (you can see it in the second snippet). Anyway, the requirement was to have the port configurable in a database.